# HTML5 Video is making LayerSlider WP break on autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, video, autoplay

The video is intended to autoplay but it is making the slider not appear at all... it breaks it... It works only on safari but not on chrome or firefox

```
<video id="video1" width="945" height="600" controls>
<source src="http://fistart.org/videos/FistArt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video.
</video>


<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 
myVideo.onloadeddata=myVideo.play(); 
</script>
```

Comment: You say it works on Safari but not on Chrome or Safari. That doesn't make sense.  Also, show us more code.  We need to see this is context.

Comment: http://fistart.org/new-home/  @Chris Herbert it makes none, but what i was supposed to say was it works on safari but not on chrome and firefox... that is all the code i use on LayeSlider plugin on wordpress...